# CSRF=True but seems not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 3.1.5 in PHP 5.6 Apache Ubuntu 16.04. The CSRF token set to TRUE in config like shown below:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'name_token';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'name_cookie';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 600;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

I use `form_open()` so the token automatically insert in form by CI. At first, it seems work properly. Yet, I tried to manipulate the token by deleting some chars/or even delete all the token trough inspect element and submit the form to see if it really work. I surprised the CI did not show the "The action you have requested is not allowed" page as result. I tried also to use form tag so I write `<input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />` manually. And again after made some manipulation to the token, it didn't show "The action you have requested is not allowed" page as result. Any idea why?

Comment: Well I just tested out a vanilla 3.1.5. and 3.1.6 install and I dread saying this - but - It Works For Me! I performed the same skull duggery you did on the csrf tokens and each time it got very upset with me and displayed the error message.

Comment: Are you using a copy of CI from the CI Website or have you obtained this from "other" sources?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I am using a copy from CI website a few months ago before 3.1.6 came up.

Comment: ok here's my plan: I'll download a fresh copy of 3.1.6 CI and I'll test it. I'll update the result. If it works, then there is something wrong on my 3.1.5 CI. Thank you for your attention, Sir @TimBrownlaw

Comment: You are welcome and that's a good strategy to at least eliminate any funnies in the code base you have :)

Comment: There's only one function in system/core/Security.php csrf_verify() which you could put var_dumps and exits in and poke around it...

Comment: Did you get anywhere with it?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I apologize forgot to tell you, I downgraded my ubuntu to 14.04 and everything works fine. Cheers..

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! That is interesting. I forgot to tell you I was running ubuntu 14.04. Were you running on a LAMP stack on 16.04? It shouldn't matter... but then I aint tried it on 16.04 to confirm it.